# AsyncTask crashes my app

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a problem with AsyncTask, when I use this function, 90% of it   crashes and I don't know why. What can I do about it?
obs: ignore the return type

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(ArrayList<cldetailday>... params){
boolean HaveOpenHour = false;
ArrayList<String> lstHours = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<cldetailday> lstdetail = new ArrayList<cldetailday>();
Time _time = new Time();
_time.hour = 0;
_time.minute = 0;
try {
        lstdetail = params[0];  
         if(lstdetail != null & lstdetail.size() > 0){
             for(int i = 0; i < lstdetail.size(); i++){
                 lstHours.add(lstdetail.get(i).getHora());
                 if(((i+1)%2 == 0)){                             
                     // Fechei um lancamento
                     HaveOpenHour = true;
                     _time.hour += UtilsDate.Instance().TimeDiff(lstHours.get(i-1),lstHours.get(i)).getHour();
                     _time.minute += UtilsDate.Instance().TimeDiff(lstHours.get(i-1),lstHours.get(i)).getMinute();
                 }
                 else{
                     HaveOpenHour = false;
                 }
             }
         }
         // Temos horas em aberto, inserimos a hora atual para fechar esse lancamento
         if(!HaveOpenHour){
             // temos alguem na lista para processar horas
             if(lstHours != null && lstHours.size() > 0){
                  clHour hour = UtilsDate.Instance().getCurrentHour();

                 _time.hour += UtilsDate.Instance().TimeDiff(lstHours.get(lstHours.size() - 1), hour.getStringHour()).getHour();
                 _time.minute += UtilsDate.Instance().TimeDiff(lstHours.get(lstHours.size() - 1), hour.getStringHour()).getMinute();
                 _time.normalize(true);

             }
         }          
    return true;        
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    Log.e("Error doBackground: ", e.getMessage());
    return false;
}
```

Error:

```
09-25 20:27:15.576: E/AndroidRuntime(566): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
09-25 20:27:15.576: E/AndroidRuntime(566): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-25 20:27:15.576: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
09-25 20:27:15.576: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
09-25 20:27:15.576: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
09-25 20:27:15.576: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
09-25 20:27:15.576: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
09-25 20:27:15.576: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
09-25 20:27:15.576: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
09-25 20:27:15.576: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
09-25 20:27:15.576: E/AndroidRuntime(566): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
09-25 20:27:15.576: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
09-25 20:27:15.576: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:230)
09-25 20:27:15.576: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at com.wpa.pontoeletronico.GetTotalHour.doInBackground(GetTotalHour.java:71)
09-25 20:27:15.576: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at com.wpa.pontoeletronico.GetTotalHour.doInBackground(GetTotalHour.java:1)
09-25 20:27:15.576: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-25 20:27:15.576: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
09-25 20:27:15.576: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  ... 4 more
```

Comment: It appears like some exception has occured and in the exception block, your log.e is crashing with NullPointerException. What is the line 71. Also, add breakpoint and try to debug doInBackground()

Comment: thanks everyone, I´m going to test it,but is it normal "Exception e" return null? I have never seen it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Log.e("Error doBackground: ", e.getMessage());
```

change to

```
Log.wtf("Your asyntask TAG","Error doBackground: ",e);
```

A possible reason why this might happen is that e.getMessage() return no messages, while in the Log.wtf method, you can pass your exception instance in the method(can be null) on the 3rd argument.

Comment: thanks everyone, I´m going to test it,but is it normal "Exception e" return null? I have never seen it before

Answer (score 0):

It's failing in the line

```
Log.e("Error doBackground: ", e.getMessage());
```

isn't it?

Your exception `e` object doesn't have a message and returns `null` on `e.getMessage()`.

Comment: thanks everyone, I´m going to test it,but is it normal "Exception e" return null? I have never seen it before

Comment: Exception is not null. It just doesn't have a message to return.